# Plane Cremona groups over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, projective-geometry, birational-geometry

Many research has been done on Cremona groups - the *Cremona group $\mathrm{Cr}(\mathbb{P}^d(k))$ in dimension $d$ over a field $k$* is the group of birational transformations of $\mathbb{P}^d(k)$. (Many other equivalent definitions exist; e.g., it can also be defined as the $k$-automorphism group of $k(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$.) 
 I have done some browsing, and usually I seem to come up with pages and papers where $k = \mathbb{C}$, where $k$ is algebraically closed, etc. In any case, "usually" $k$ seems to be infinite.

QUESTION: What are the big results known when $k$ is finite ? How is the $k$ finite case essentially different from the $k$ infinite case ? What about the case $d = 2$ ?

Comment: Concerning the Cremona group, most of the results for $\mathbf{C}$ only use that it's al algebraically closed of characteristic zero. I don't know what you mean by "seems" to be infinite. Usually the main issue is whether the field is assumed algebraically closed, or whether it's assumed of zero characteristic. Some results have been shown for arbitrary fields. Some reduce to finite fields. Anyway it's a bit too broad, there are many recent results. I don't quote anything precise although I have several in mind; I'm not comfortable with opinion-based "what are the big results?".

Comment: The Bourbaki lecture by Serre (November 2008) contains a number of results valid over any perfect field.

Comment: @YCor: do you have examples of interesting results for finite fields which do not hold for $\mathbb{C}$ ?